# How to load openapi local files into swagger on localhost? (Files generated by restdocs)

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, springdoc, spring-restdocs

I have my api documentation generated by restdocs through unit tests. Although it works fine for most of my needs, I'm still lacking a bit of the nice swagger features, so I was trying to have the best of both words by converting the restdocs into swagger. After trying for a long time, I finally managed to get it done with the help of some third part libraries (https://github.com/ePages-de/restdocs-api-spec https://github.com/BerkleyTechnologyServices/restdocs-spec). This generates the open api files under the static docs folder. However, when I try to access the swagger url http://localhost:8081/swagger-ui/index.html, It wouldn't show it there, which would have worked by default if adding swagger directly with the swagger annotation on the controller. I can manually import the openapi yml file and see it through the https://editor.swagger.io/ but there may be a better way to map swagger to automatically find the openapi files directly from my code so I can keep using the default swagger url for this?

Thank you.

```
 <plugin>
        <groupId>io.github.berkleytechnologyservices</groupId>
            <artifactId>restdocs-spec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${restdocs-spec.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!--suppress MavenModelInspection -->
                        <skip>${skipTests}</skip>
                        <host>localhost:8081</host>
                        <specification>OPENAPI_V3</specification>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/static/docs</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

[image]

[image]

UPDATE

Trying with the docs under the resources folder, but still getting the same error. I've opened a new question with details here [Failed to load api definition when loading files from application properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75280424/failed-to-load-api-definition-when-loading-files-from-application-properties)

[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have need to put the openapi specification yml in the resource folder and set `springdoc.swagger-ui.url=/openapi-3.yaml` in the application.properties file of spring boot app.

Checkout [springdoc api documentation](https://springdoc.org/#what-is-a-proper-way-to-set-up-swagger-ui-to-use-provided-spec-yml)

In application properties need to make sure

```
spring.web.resources.add-mappings=false
```

shouldn't be added its preventing to serve static content.

Also `openapi-3.0.yml` should be placed inside of `resources/static` folder.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've just tried this now, but I'm afraid I'm still getting the same error. Tried both with .yml and .yaml. The post is updated accordingly.

Comment: I've opened a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75280424/failed-to-load-api-definition-when-loading-files-from-application-properties

Comment: probably issue with openapi configuration bean. If possible please share sample github link.

Comment: https://github.com/francislainy/HelloTalk/tree/swagger Thank you.

Comment: I got the issue. Updating the answer

Comment: I have working code of your git repo. In case if you want I will raise PR if needed.

Comment: Sure, that would be really great if you can do that. Thank you very much. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Please review and merge the pull request.
https://github.com/francislainy/HelloTalk/pull/1