# Failed to load api definition when loading files from application properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc

I have an openapi file generated through restdocs and converted into this format. They are added to the resources folder, and the properties file is pointing to their format, however, swagger is failing to load and I'm not sure what else I could be missing.

[image]

[image]

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-restdocs-mockmvc.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springdoc-openapi-ui.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>capital.scalable</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-auto-restdocs-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-auto-restdocs-core.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.epages</groupId>
            <artifactId>restdocs-api-spec</artifactId>
            <version>${restdocs-api-spec.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.epages</groupId>
            <artifactId>restdocs-api-spec-mockmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${restdocs-api-spec.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

       <plugin>
                <groupId>io.github.berkleytechnologyservices</groupId>
                <artifactId>restdocs-spec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${restdocs-spec.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!--suppress MavenModelInspection -->
                            <skip>${skipTests}</skip>
                            <host>localhost:8081</host>
                            <specification>OPENAPI_V3</specification>
                            
     <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/static/docs</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A related question was posted here and this answer solved the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75273492/6654475

In summary, it was related to this line that needed to be removed `spring.web.resources.add-mappings=false` and the yml file that needed to be moved to the `resources/static/` folder.